# Script that will set caps lock as upper or lower by choice

Tags: capslock

I am using Arch Linux and Openbox window manager with all the latset updates

For years I have struggled with the caps lock key.

I never know it's status until I come to use it.

The same for all of us.

I have to push it a few times,
and experiment to find out where it is,
upper or lower,
then get it where I want it,
upper or lower

Obviously a huge waste of time

I am planning to

- leave caps lock key as a toggle caps key
- assign = key to upper case
- assign # key to lower case

I believe this will be much simpler

I can use a script to release these keys if necessary and put everything back to default as I am sure will be necessary now and again

How can I distinctly get set either upper or lower case via a script?

Comment: This won't answer your question, would you be open to a more sophisticated distro like Linux Mint, there are these options: https://i.imgur.com/0xGB9Uh.png

Comment: Mint is doing lots of interesting stuff there. No doub't Mint has evolved a lot since I first tried it out years ago. I won't be moving through. Because I have a very highly evolved system that does almost everything I need. Anything I need can generally be done with scripting. Just need to know how to distinctly set UPPER or lower distinctly from script. Rest is easy after that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two short scripts that turn on lower case or upper case.
One script turns on upper case, the other turns on lower case, regardless of whether that particular case is already keyboard selected.

Each script can be assigned it's own hot key as you desire.

The scripts use `xset` and `xdotool` utilities, but these are small and easy to install.

**Set the keyboard to upper case**

```
#!/bin/bash


# set caps lock to UPPER CASE


# get status of caps lock 
caps_lock_status=$(xset q | grep "Caps Lock:" | awk '{print $4}') 
echo $caps_lock_status

# on  = UPPER CASE
# off = lower


# If Caps Lock is off, toggle it on
if [[ "$caps_lock_status" == "off" ]]; then
 
    # toggles caps lock to off  
    xdotool key Caps_Lock
fi
```

**Set the keyboard to lower case**

```
#!/bin/bash

# set caps lock to lower case


# get status of caps lock 
caps_lock_status=$(xset q | grep "Caps Lock:" | awk '{print $4}') 
echo $caps_lock_status

# on  = UPPER CASE
# off = lower


# If Caps Lock is on, toggle it off
if [[ "$caps_lock_status" == "on" ]]; then
 
    # toggles caps lock to off  
    xdotool key Caps_Lock
fi
```